# Custom url for images hosted on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I am currently using Amazon S3 to host and serve my website's images. For example, the link looks like this:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/images/tn_1014.jpg

What I would like to do is have the path look something more like our original site's path, such as:

http://www.mySiteName.com/images/tn_1014.jpg

How / Where about would I go to set this up. I imagine it may be some sort of mapping somewhere, I'm just not sure where. I run a VPS box with IIS and Railo. Is it something I set up on the webserver or somewhere in the DNS settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the tutorial at http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/ to alias your domain to your S3 bucket.

Comment: What about full path aliasing? (ie bucket contains /tnetnftf/tnefntfetf/bl3827023.jpg but aliased path should be mydomain.com/images/happy.jpg) @Stanley

Comment: This is outdated

Comment: This is a link-only answer.